# R Matrix, get the index of minimum column

Tags: r

I am very new to R, I am learning.
 I have calculated the difference, column wise like this. (difference with omega)

```
final_wights <- apply(wjs,2, function(x) (omega - x))^2
```

Now i want to get the column number of the minimum column. I can get minimum column value using

`col <- apply(final_wights, 2, min)`,

But i want to get the index of that how do i just get the index column number in the matrix

Comment: Use `which(final_wights == min(final_wights))` to get the index or indices of the entries in `final_wights` that are equal to the minimum.

Comment: @bhas if i understand min(final_wights)) would give me the minimum element ? not the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not need `apply` here

```
final_weights <-  (wjs-omega)^2
```

To get the index of the columns with minimum values, you can use `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE` to get the 'row/column' index (a modification of @Bhas comments)

```
which(final_weights == min(final_weights), arr.ind=TRUE)[,2]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
wjs <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:20, 5*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
set.seed(42)
omega <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:20, 5*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
```

Comment: I was typing the data details,  so my wjs is a 60x60 matrix and so is omega, it is column wise subtraction. So after doing that i need to find min column.

Comment: @Anup What is the dimension of `omega`?  Is it a vector with length 60  or matrix 60*60

Comment: Got that, i knew there was a good way to do this. Omega is also a 60x60 matrix. Thanks

Comment: In that case also my code works as they are the same dimensions.